# How to put values from a HashMap into an array

Tags: kotlin

How can I add all values from a `HashMap` into a `String` array? For example, I have:

```
var tablica = arrayListOf<String>()

var haszmapa = hashMapOf<String, Int>()
haszmapa.put("Tadek", 1)
haszmapa.put("Maniek", 1)
haszmapa.put("Juras", 1)
```

Comment: What is the expected output, and what have you tried? Are you looking for a list of `["Tadek", "Maniek", "Juras"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this using `map`:

```
val hashMap = hashMapOf("Tadek" to 1, "Maniek" to 1, "Juras" to 1)

val names = hashMap.keys.toTypedArray()
val values = hashMap.values.toTypedArray()
```

Note: That you can use the vararg argument of `hashMapOf` as shown above right away if you don't want to fill the map dynamically. The type `HashMap<String, Int>` can then be inferred as well, so there is no need to specify it explicitely.

Comment: This can be even more concise: `val names = hashMap.keys.toList()`